# How can I generate an error::Error instance?

Tags: rust

I'm implementing a function as part of trait like so:

```
impl TryFrom<(i16, i16, i16)> for Color {
    type Error = Box<dyn error::Error>;
    fn try_from(tuple: (i16, i16, i16)) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {

        if tuple.0 < 0 || tuple.1 < 0 || tuple.2 < 0 || tuple.0 > 255 || tuple.1 > 255 || tuple.2 >255 {
            return Err(Box::new(error::Error)); //how do I generate an instance of an error?
        }

        let c = Self { red: tuple.0 as u8, green: tuple.1 as u8, blue: tuple.2 as u8 };
        Ok(c)
    }
}
```

And I can't figure out how to generate an instance of an errror in the if statement. I've tried all of the below and none work. The compiler just isn't happy.

```
Err(Box::new(error::Error));
Err(Box::new(Error));
Err(Box::new(error::Error::new()));
Err(Box::new(error::Error::new("123")));
```

I've looked at [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html) for `std::error::Error` but I can't find an answer there. I'm new to Rust so pardon if this is stupid.

If there's some fundamental misunderstanding on my part, please let me know / point to resources I can read.

Comment: please provide a [mcve]

Comment: I advice you to read about how is handle error in general in rust. I personalty advice to use crate like https://crates.io/crates/snafu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::error::Error` is a trait, not a type, so you cannot directly create an instance of it. You need to choose an existing type that implements the trait (or write a new one), and use that.

If you just need an error message, you can make use of `From<&str>` being implemented for `Box<dyn Error>`, and write:

```
return Err(Box::from("your message here"));
```

You can use any other error type as well, such as [`std::io::Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.Error.html):

```
use std::io;
return Err(Box::new(io::Error::new(io::ErrorKind::Other, "your message here")));
```

Comment: Wow that makes so much sense. I actually started with exactly std::io::Error::new() and then I was wondering why can't I do the same with error::Error.. Thanks for this!

Comment: Why use `std::io::Error` when it makes no sense? It's better to use `&str` and the `From<&str> for Box<dyn std::error::Error>` impl.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Good point. To be honest, I simply didn't know about the `From<&str>` for `Box<dyn Error>` impl. I've now amended the answer to include this simpler form.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple example that creates an instance of `Err` and returns an `Error` using `?`:

```rust
use std::env;

fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    let args: Vec<String> = env::args().collect();
    println!("args: {:?}", args);

    if args.len() < 2 {
        println!("Usage: {0} <arg1>", args[0]);
        Err("Invalid CLI arguments")?  // <--- Return an error
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

[Try it in the Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=64e52c6ce5e897f53385ab414eeddc91)